# Store radio button value in database on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to store values of radio button in database. These are my 3 files

The main issue is button type is 'button'. Php script can be written if the type is 'submit'. This can be solved using javascript but I have never used it.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Audio</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p> This is a test system </p>
    <audio id="song" src="file/A1.wav" controls></audio>
    <form id="submit_value" method="post" action="dbconnect.php">
        <input type="radio" id="happy" name="emotion" value="happy">
        <label>Happy</label><br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="nextAudio(); save();"> NEXT </button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="audio.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file

On Next button click, it is changing audio saved in an array and for every audio I have to save radio button value in database

```
const song = document.querySelector('#song');

audioIndex = 0;

myAudio = ['file/A1.wav', 'file/A2.wav', 'file/A3.wav'];

function nextAudio() {
    //alert("in javascript");
    audioIndex++;
    song.src = myAudio[audioIndex];
}
function save()
{
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

PHP file

```
<?php
$hostname= "localhost";
$username= "root";
$password= "";
$dbname="project";

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("not success". $conn->connect_error);
}
else
{
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
if (isset($_POST['emotion']))
{
    $emotion = $_POST['emotion'];
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO answers (Id, Emotion) VALUES ('NULL', 'happy')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo "Inserted";
}
else
{
    echo "Error : ". $sql. "<br>".$conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Now it is going to the save() function but is still not storing the values in the database. It is redirecting to the PHP page.

[[image: After clicking next button[1]]

Answer (score 0):

You can manually `submit` your form on click of your `button` using `.submit()` method of `js` . Working code :

```js
function save(){
//getting id of form and then submit it to server 
document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="yourpagename">
     <input type="radio" id="happy" name="emotion" value="happy">
     <label >Happy</label><br/>
     <button type="button" onclick=" save();"> NEXT </button>
     </form>
```

Comment: thank you !!!!
I need to know that

<form id="form" method="post" action="yourpagename">

"yourpagename" this should be .PHP or .js

I have a separate .js file

Comment: `yourpagename` should be your `.php` page name .

Comment: Also, as per your current js code your form need to have `id="submit_value"` because in your js code you have use `const val = document.querySelector('#submit_value');` but your form doesn't have any id with that name , assign id to `<form>` and check onces.

Comment: thank you !!!
I did that too...just forgot to write here
Still doesn't work

Comment: what doesn't work can you elaborate it more? also does your browser console shows any error?

Comment: It is not going to the PHP file....no errors on console or browser; it is executing the function in JS file but not PHP......moreover I updated my HTML code

Comment: you don't submit any inputs with `name="submit"` so, this line `if(isset($_POST['submit']))..` will always be false . removed this line instead write `if(isset($_POST['emotion']))` and check onces,

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['emotion']))
{
    $emotion= $_POST['emotion'];
}
$sqlQuery="Insert into answers (Emotion) VALUES ('$emotion')";`

Comment: Is this what you are saying??

Comment: Yes ,check and see if that works , also try to print `mysqli_error` if still that doesn’t work

Comment: It is still not giving me the error...but is redirecting to the PHP page !!!! I updated the code and attached the screenshot as well

Comment: you are running your php on localhost or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You could send your data to backend using javascript `Ajax` fetch api.
And handle this data in backend with php.

Javascript:

```
async function nextAudio() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('<backend-url>', {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                emotion: document.getElementById("happy").checked
            }),
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            }
        });
        chck_alert();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="song" src="file/A1.wav" controls></audio>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" id="happy" name="emotion" value="happy">
        <label>Happy</label><br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="nextAudio(); "> NEXT </button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ajax:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="nextAudio()" id="submit_button"> NEXT </button>
<script>
$("#submit_button").submit(function() {
var emotion =$('input[name="emotion"]:checked').val();
$.ajax({  
       url:"url",//give url here of controller or method which you are using to save data  
       method:"POST",  
       data:{emotion:emotion},  
       success:function(data){  
       //success
        }  
    });  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `submit` the form with default behavior using `Jquery`. A simple working snippet.

```html
<form method="post" action="nameofpage" id="submit_form">
  <input type="radio" id="happy" name="emotion" value="happy" />
  <label>Happy</label><br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('submit_form').submit()"> NEXT </button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you !!!

what should be the name of the page .PHP file ??

Comment: ofcourse `nameofpage.php` file, here you don't need `.js` file. In form action just give your  `.php` page name and your radio button value will be there. After that You can access it  like `$_POST['emotion'];`

Comment: instead of this`isset($_POST['submit'])` use this `isset($_POST['emotion'])` also `echo $emotion;` and see what you get. If you recieve value then declare `$emotion = ' ';` above `if` statement.

Comment: It is still not giving me the error...but is redirecting to the PHP page !!!! I updated the code and attached the screenshot as well